# detecting installer iptables and firewalld with if conditions / bash

Tags: bash, iptables, firewalld

Creating script to detect

- installer (yum or apt-get)
- iptables
- firewalld

Current system:

- Debian 8
- iptables NOT installed
- firewalld NOT installed

Theoretically it must be working, but missing something:

```
#!/bin/bash
installer_check () {
  if [[ $(apt-get -V >/dev/null 2>&1) -eq 0 ]]; then
    installer=apt
  elif [[ $(yum --version >/dev/null 2>&1) -eq 0 ]]; then
    installer=yum
  fi
}

frw_det_yum () {
  if [[ $(rpm -qa iptables >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]; then
    ipt_status_y=installed_none
  elif [[ $(rpm -qa firewalld >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]; then
    frd_status_y=installed_none
  fi
}

frw_det_apt () {
  if [[ $(dpkg -s iptables >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]; then
    ipt_status_a=installed_none
  elif [[ $(dpkg -s firewalld >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]; then
    frd_status_a=installed_none
  fi
}

echo "checking installer"
installer_check
echo -e "$installer detected"

if [ "$installer" = "yum" ]; then
  echo "runing firewallcheck for yum"
  frw_det_yum
  echo $ipt_status
fi

if  [ "$installer" = "apt" ]; then
  echo "checking installer for apt"
  frw_det_apt
  echo $frd_status_a
fi
```

output I'm getting:

```
~# ./script
checking installer
apt detected
checking installer for apt
```

So in this current system I'm not getting any value for `$frd_status_a`

Comment: "`if [[ $(rpm -qa iptables >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]; then`" What?

Comment: Checking a command's *output* and checking its *exit status* are entirely different things. `if rpm -q iptables >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...` is sufficient to determine whether a package is installed, relying on exit status alone. No `[[ ]]`, no `$()`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I had it that way at the beginning, but still wasn't able to get an output, so simplified this way to avoid any confusion first .... but still can't get output

Comment: "Simplified" it ain't. You're testing a completely different thing.

Comment: Anyhow, if you truly want to simplify, take out all the code not directly mandatory to show the bug your question is, at its core, about. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve discusses that process.

Comment: # dpkg -s iptables >/dev/null 2>&1    has output of 127 #echo $? output 127, its not a 0, right , why should I get  ipt_status_y=installed_none   executed, ? so echo $ipt_status_a   I understand should give an output of  installed_none ....

Comment: If `dpkg -s iptables` gives an exit status of 127, then `if ! dpkg -s iptables; then ...` will execute. It **doesn't** tell you anything at all about what `if [[ $(dpkg -s iptables >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]` will do, because that latter one is testing the **stdout** of the `dpkg` command, not the exit status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *expect* the body of the following to be invoked if `firewalld` is not installed:

```
if [[ $(dpkg -s firewalld >/dev/null 2>&1) -ne 0 ]]; then
  frd_status_a=installed_none
fi
```

However, let's look at what this actually does:

- redirect stdout and stderr of the command `dpkg -s firewalld` to `/dev/null`
- capture the stdout of that command, and compare it numerically to the value `0`
- If the stdout of that command (which **has no stdout** because you redirected it) has a numeric value other than 0, then we set the flag.

Of **course** that flag will never be set, no matter what the `dpkg` command does when it's invoked, and no matter what its output is.

---

Consider instead:

```
if ! dpkg-query -l firewalld; then
  frd_status_a=installed_none
fi
```